# After inactive period screen turn off for 1 second and then turn on again and just became blank black with cursor in Debian 11 Gnome

Tags: debian, gnome, screen-lock

After update to Debian 11 from 10, screen can't turn off after inactive period. It starts dim and then screen turn off for few seconds, everything seems notrmal, but then screen just turn on itself and became black and cursor show up. Lock works fine.

This happens when I use following command or setting it at gnome settings.

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 5`

Answer (score 0):

Debian 11 is not actually released yet.

As can be seen [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/) at the time of this writing Debian 11 'Bullseye' is still in the testing phase, with no release date set.

If you've deliberately chosen to use a Debian release that is not considered production ready yet, you shouldn't be surprised when bugs still crop up.

Try using the `reportbug` command to make as comprehensive and succinct report of the bug, what exactly happens as well as the steps to reproduce as best you're able, and hopefully the maintainers will be able to figure out what's going wrong and make sure that by the time the release is ready, it won't.

**EDIT** After re-reading your question, I realized that filling out an [upgrade report](https://release.debian.org/upgrade-report.html) might also be useful.

Comment: I accidentally installed bullseye, firefox stoped updating, and the only possible way install firefox through debian is allowing experimental packages (yes, I know about snap and etc...), and so... I allowed it but forgot to allow only firefox. 

Now I am average experimental enjoyer.

Comment: You want `firefox-esr` for that.

Comment: No, I don't. I want firefox. I know what esr is.

Comment: It's the Extended Support Release for firefox. Basically it's literally what you want.

Comment: No. I don't. I want LATEST FIREFOX VERSION.

Comment: That's exactly what you *get* when you install firefox-esr. https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/enterprise/